# JQuery Img Attr request get headers sent by the server

Tags: jquery, http-headers, response

What I want to do is use jQuery to request an image (a graph in this case).
In jQuery I'm setting the `src` attribute on my image which pulls down the graph from the server as expected.

```
$("#graphImage").attr("src", graphUrl);
```

I want to be able to send some Header information down with this request and have jQuery read it.

How can I do this. A friend of mine recommended downloading the image using ajax to a blob then writing the blob to the image tag...not sure how this can be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for Non IE browsers < 7. For

```
$.ajax({
  url: graphUrl,//This will be a page which will return the base64 encoded string
  headers: {},//Pass the required header information
  success: function(response){
     $("#graphImage").attr("src", response);
  }
});
```

**Code to convert image to base64 string**

```
public string ImageToBase64(Image image, 
  System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat format)
{
  using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
  {
    // Convert Image to byte[]
    image.Save(ms, format);
    byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();

    // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
    string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
    return base64String;
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. response must be a url, not binary data. I want to recieve headers, not send them.

Comment: It works for all the browsers except `IE < 7`. I am using it in my project.

Comment: so I have do do something different on the server, encode the response into base64?

Comment: Wow, this is awesome. I don't even have to use headers anymore. I can pass the string down in a json document with other information as needed. Sweet!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about reading the response to load an image but pulling the response headers is straight forward.

```
jQuery.ajax({
  url: '/img/foo.gif',
  complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
    var h = jqXHR.getResponseHeader('Content-Type');
    alert(h);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know how to do this either.